# Unity game crashes in standalone on one specific scene?

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine

My game works perfectly fine in the Unity editor. When building to standalone macOS, every scene works, except my main game loop, it crashes with this error.

```
Crashed Thread:        12  UnityGfxDeviceWorker

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MTLIGSampler textureType]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000244c20'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I google "unity nsexception" and there are multiple forums questions with answers, did you try any of that?

Comment: Open a support ticket anyway. This will improve unity in future releases.

Comment: I have found some additional information with what is causing the crash.
I suppose mac build cannot find streaming assets?
```Could not find a part of the path "/Users/pythug/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~Preview/Documents/myapp.app/Contents/StreamingAssets/Enemies.json"```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a multi-monitor set-up? [Unity Forums](https://forum.unity.com/threads/crashes-inside-unitygfxdeviceworker.466298/) think it could be a related issue. Seems to be an elusive bug...

Comment: No just my laptop =/

Comment: In which case I suggest doing as Meikel said and open a support ticket with Unity.